# Can you pull a timestamp from a preceding record and check a condition?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a sample table below that shows a list of calls of each employee. Example: On Jan 1 Emp A took 4 calls, B took 4, etc. I am trying to find some anomalies within the start and end times for some calls. The end time for the Previous call cannot be more then the start time of the next call. Example: **Call ID: 2** has a discrepancy. The call "ended" at 12:30 AM, but Emp A was on another call at 12:20 AM contradicting the call end time for call id 2. I am trying to write a script to flag these calls. The script will have to partition by Date first then partition by Emp then order by Time. Can this be done?

```
Call ID  Date    Emp   StartTime   EndTime
1        Jan 1   A     12:00 AM    12:10 AM
2        Jan 1   A     12:15 AM    12:30 AM
3        Jan 1   A     12:20 AM    12:45 AM
4        Jan 1   A     12:50 AM    1:00  AM
5        Jan 1   B     2:00  AM    2:30  AM
6        Jan 1   B     2:25  AM    2:50  AM
7        Jan 1   B     3:00  AM    3:50  AM
8        Jan 1   B     3:45  AM    4:00  AM
9        Jan 1   C     12:30 AM    12:45 AM
10       Jan 1   C     1:00  AM    1:30  AM
11       Jan 1   C     1:45  AM    1:50  AM
12       Jan 1   C     2:00  AM    2:10  AM
13       Jan 2   A     ...         ...
14       Jan 2   A     ...         ...
15       Jan 2   B     ...         ...
```

**Result**

```
Call ID   Incorrect EndTime
2         12:30 AM
5         2:30  AM
7         3:50  AM
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exists` to get overlaps:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.emp = t.emp and
                    t2.date = t.date and
                    t2.starttime < t.endtime and
                    t2.endtime > t.starttime
             );
```

Note:  This assume that no calls span midnight.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're looking to determine incorrect overlap based on `LEAD(StartTime)` versus EndTime.  The `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` for the `LEAD` function correspond to what's in the question.

```
with lead_cte as (
    select *, lead(StartTime) over (partition by [Date], Emp 
                                    order by StartTime) lead_start
    from calls)
select CallID, EndTime as [Incorrect EndTime]
from lead_cte
where EndTime>lead_start;
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked. I had no knowledge of LEAD. Super helpful. (Forgot to respond)

Answer (score 0):

Use LEAD function.

```
SELECT
    CallID,
    Date,
    Emp,
    StartTime,
    EndTime,
    LEAD (StartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Emp, Date ORDER BY StartTime) AS StartTimeNextCall, --this is for information
    CASE 
        WHEN (LEAD (StartTime) OVER (PARTITION BY Emp, Date ORDER BY StartTime)) > EndTime
        THEN 'discrepancy'
        ELSE 'ok'
    END AS Flag
FROM tab;
```

Obs.: I assume that column Date contains only the day, and not the time, otherwise the PARTITION BY clause must be different